# Javascript Syntax Error on click

Tags: javascript, html

I keep on getting a syntax error in this HTML/JavaScript code and I can't seem to figure out why.

Any ideas?

```
<li onClick="document.getElementById(\'attribute83\').selectedIndex ="2", spConfig.configureElement($("attribute83")); class="some-css-class"><a href="http://www.example.com">Something</a></li>'
```

Comment: Because the original poster is using PHP to output the Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your onClick handler has a syntax error.

The web browser will take everything between the two quote on your onClick handler

```
onClick="document.getElementById('attribute83').selectedIndex ="2"
```

which means

```
document.getElementById(\'attribute83\').selectedIndex ="2
```

This isn't valid javascript.  If you're using onclick handlers you can have the quotes used to enclose your html attribute (") in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li onClick="Click()", spConfig.configureElement($("attribute83")); class="some-css-class"><a href="http://www.example.com">Something</a></li>'

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Click()
   {
      document.getElementById('attribute83').selectedIndex = "2";
   }

</script>
```